# Isolate Android system when connected to wifi

Tags: wifi, android

Is there any built-in feature or application that isolates the system when it's connected to a wlan, so that just a determined app has access to the net?

For example, let's say that you want to analyze a public access point with an application, but you don't want to recieve messages, email...  while you are connected to that AP. Is it possible to just allow that app access to the network?

Answer (score 1):

Using something like [NoRootFirewall](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/02/10/control-apps-may-access-internet-android-device/) gives you full access over what apps can access the internet. It sets up a VPN connection to route all traffic through so it has full control over what app can access the internet.

You could either install this app, or incorporate similar behavior in your app e.g. when this app runs block all others.